# biblatex: Setting maxbibnames option truncates to first name + et al., not to the maxbibnames value

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm using: `biblatex` 1.7.1; `biber` (0.9.6 I guess) and working on LyX on Kubuntu 12.04.
For example, I'm setting in my `.bbx` file the value to `6`:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    maxbibnames = 6
}
```

But in the reference list the references aren't truncated after 6 names as I would expect but rather displays only 1 name + et al. (only for entries with more than 6 authors, of course). But if I set it to say `maxbibnames =99` then I get the full list of authors.
The style I'm basing on calls for `authoryear.bbx` which truncates itself to the first name + et al. if there are more than 6 authors.

Why is that?

Comment: I believe you want `maxbibnames=6, minbibnames=6`, but I'm not 100% sure (I don't use BibLaTeX at all).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

tohecz is right, you need to set `minbibnames=6` as well. Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (section 3.1.2.1):

> **`maxnames=<integer>`** default: `3`
>  A threshold affecting all lists of names (author, editor, etc.). If a list exceeds this
>   threshold, i. e., if it holds more than `<integer>` names, it is
>   automatically truncated according to the setting of the `minnames`
>   option. `maxnames` is the master option which sets both `maxbibnames`
>   and `maxcitenames`.
>
> **`minnames=<integer>`** default: `1`
>  A limit affecting all lists of names (author, editor, etc.). If a list holds more than `maxnames`
>   names, it is automatically truncated to `minnames` names. The
>   `minnames` value must be smaller than or equal to `maxnames`.
>   `minnames` is the master option which sets both `minbibnames` and
>   `mincitenames`.
>
> **`maxbibnames=<integer>`** default: `maxnames`
>  Similar to `maxnames` but affects only the bibliography.
>
> **`minbibnames=<integer>`** default: `minnames`
>  Similar to `minnames` but affects only the bibliography.