# Add et al. to truncated formatted list of authors in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I had the same issue as described in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76240/biblatex-setting-maxbibnames-option-truncates-to-first-name-et-al-not-to-th), having to truncate a long list of authors by use of `maxbibnames=9`. As I also want a specific format for the names `Lastname, F.`, that seems not to work together. Is there a way to include the added et al. while keeping the names formatted like that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,         % Seitenformat
        12pt,                   % Schriftgröße
        bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis
        parskip=false,
        abstract=on             % Erstellt Titel für Abstract
        ]{scrreprt}


\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@misc{Abadi.2016,
 author = {Abadi, Martin and Agarwal, Ashish and Barham, Paul and Brevdo, Eugene and Chen, Zhifeng and Citro, Craig and Corrado, Greg S. and Davis, Andy and Dean, Jeffrey and Devin, Matthieu and Ghemawat, Sanjay and Goodfellow, Ian and Harp, Andrew and Irving, Geoffrey and Isard, Michael and Jia, Yangqing and Jozefowicz, Rafal and Kaiser, Lukasz and Kudlur, Manjunath and Levenberg, Josh and Mane, Dan and Monga, Rajat and Moore, Sherry and Murray, Derek and Olah, Chris and Schuster, Mike and Shlens, Jonathon and Steiner, Benoit and Sutskever, Ilya and Talwar, Kunal and Tucker, Paul and Vanhoucke, Vincent and Vasudevan, Vijay and Viegas, Fernanda and Vinyals, Oriol and Warden, Pete and Wattenberg, Martin and Wicke, Martin and Yu, Yuan and Zheng, Xiaoqiang},
 year = {2016},
 title = {TensorFlow: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Distributed Systems},
 url = {http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04467v2},
 keywords = {Computer Science - Distributed Parallel and Cluster Computing;Computer Science - Learning}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
            natbib=true, 
            backend=biber, 
            maxcitenames=2,
            uniquelist=false,
            doi=false, 
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false,
            maxbibnames=9,
            minbibnames=9]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib} % note the .bib is required

% Lastname, F.
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
   \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
   {\namepartfamily}
   {\namepartgiveni}
   {\namepartprefix}
   {\namepartsuffix}%
}%


\begin{document}

\textcite{Abadi.2016}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How ever that truncates the lists of authors very well, but doesnt add a 'et al.' at the end of the truncated list.

[image: unconstraiend version]

[image: truncated version]

Comment: This absolutely should not be happening. `biblatex` should add an "et al." when it truncates name lists unless instructed to do otherwise. I could not reproduce the output you shown in the picture from the information given so far. Please provide a *full* example document including an example `.bib` entry that reproduces the issue when compiled in a new, empty directory - a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: I was hoping that might be a common issue, but I figured out what causing it and add a MWE as well as updated the description. The problem arises because of `\usebibmacro{name:family-given}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name format for `sortname`

```
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
   \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
   {\namepartfamily}
   {\namepartgiveni}
   {\namepartprefix}
   {\namepartsuffix}%
}%
```

is incomplete. All standard name formats end with

```
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
```

to take care of the "et al." business. This line is missing in your definition.

You *could* fix this with

```
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
   \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
     {\namepartfamily}
     {\namepartgiveni}
     {\namepartprefix}
     {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}%
```

but it is much easier to use the predefined name format and just say

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

This definition has the added bonus of obeying the `giveninits` option, so you probably want to add `giveninits=true` to your loading options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
            natbib=true, 
            backend=biber, 
            maxcitenames=2,
            uniquelist=false,
            doi=false, 
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false,
            maxbibnames=9,
            minbibnames=9,
            giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Abadi.2016,
  author      = {Abadi, Martin and Agarwal, Ashish and Barham, Paul
                 and Brevdo, Eugene and Chen, Zhifeng and Citro, Craig
                 and Corrado, Greg S. and Davis, Andy and Dean, Jeffrey
                 and Devin, Matthieu and Ghemawat, Sanjay and Goodfellow, Ian
                 and Harp, Andrew and Irving, Geoffrey and Isard, Michael
                 and Jia, Yangqing and Jozefowicz, Rafal and Kaiser, Lukasz
                 and Kudlur, Manjunath and Levenberg, Josh and Mane, Dan
                 and Monga, Rajat and Moore, Sherry and Murray, Derek
                 and Olah, Chris and Schuster, Mike and Shlens, Jonathon
                 and Steiner, Benoit and Sutskever, Ilya and Talwar, Kunal
                 and Tucker, Paul and Vanhoucke, Vincent and Vasudevan, Vijay
                 and Viegas, Fernanda and Vinyals, Oriol and Warden, Pete
                 and Wattenberg, Martin and Wicke, Martin and Yu, Yuan and Zheng, Xiaoqiang},
  year        = {2016},
  title       = {TensorFlow: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Distributed Systems},
  eprint      = {1603.04467v2},
  eprinttype  = {arxiv},
  eprintclass = {cs.DC},
  version     = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{Abadi.2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Abadi, M., Agarwal, A., Barham, P., Brevdo, E., Chen, Z., Citro, C., Corrado, G. S., Davis, A., Dean, J., et al. (2016). TensorFlow: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Distributed Systems. Version 2. arXiv: 1603.04467v2 [cs.DC].]

Comment: Thanks you're right, the easiest way was to use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`